# Processing.instances returns null

Tags: javascript, processing

I have a webpage running 2 processing sketches, i want to call Processing.instances[0].exit() as suggested in this question: [Dynamically "unload" a Processing JS sketch from canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178450/dynamically-unload-a-processing-js-sketch-from-canvas)

But when i call Processing.instances it returns null, and i get no errors on the javascript console - also Processing.instances.length returns (0).

Here the javascript code:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) { // or document.onkeypress
e = e || window.event;
if (e.keyCode == 115 || e.keyCode == 83) { //press "s" or "S"
    alert(Processing.instances.length);
}
};
```

And here the url for the website: http://culturadigital.cc/nuevaweb

Thanks

Comment: Also here: `var canvases = getElementsByClassName(document, 'processingsketch');
 if(canvases){
  for(j=0;j<canvases.length;j++){
   var ps= Processing.loadSketchFromSources(canvases[j], [canvases[j].getAttribute('data-processing-sources')]);
   window.alert(ps);
  }
 }` The variable ps returns "undefined" is that not strange? the sketches load very well though // so confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out from the pjs forum, Processing.instances is in uncertain fate. How about this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) { // or document.onkeypress
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == 115 || e.keyCode == 83) { //press "s" or "S"
    var canvases = document.getElementsByClassName("processingsketch");
            window.alert(canvases.length);
    if (canvases) {
      var ps = Array();
      for (j=0;j<canvases.length;j++) {
        ps[j]=Processing.getInstanceById(canvases[j].getAttribute('id'));
      }
      for (j=0;j<canvases.length;j++) {
        window.alert("ps " + ps[j]);
        window.alert(canvases[j].getAttribute('id'));
        if(ps[j]){ps[j].exit();} //per fartagaintuxedo's comment below: to avoid second error because once it exits then there is no longer an instance in that canvas
        canvases[j].width = canvases[j].width; //to obliterate the canvas instead of just freezing it
      }
    }
  }
};
```

For reference, there might be better ways to clear the canvas here: [How to clear the canvas for redrawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)

Comment: apparently `exit` should make the sketch not visible.. what happens here is that it freezes.. strange.. then the second time i press "s" i get the same error again

Comment: but i guess thats just what it has to do.. just freeze, why not.

Comment: just a note, to avoid second error *because once it exits then there is no longer an instance in that canvas* just add `if(ps[j]){ps[j].exit();}`

Comment: You probably then just have to play with js/html and the canvas. For example you can add `canvases[j].width = canvases[j].width;` after ps[j].exit();

Comment: yep, great! that will do : )

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else finds this question: don't use Processing.instances - we never wrote it to be accessible. There is a Processing.getInstanceById() function that you pass in your canvas id, and get back the sketch that's running on it.

Get your instance with `.getInstanceById()`, then call `.exit()` on that.